# Por quê o print não retorna todos os itens de uma lista?

Tags: python, if, else

O seguinte código deveria retornar todos os carros da seguinte lista:

```
cars = ['audi','bmw','subaru','toyota']

for car in cars:
    if car == 'bmw':
        print(car.upper())
else:
    print(car.title())
```

Mas só retornou:
BMW
Toyota

O que há de errado?

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o problema: https://ideone.com/8RqW2K

Comment: Que estranho. Eu estou usando o IDLE. Vou testar no Atom. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código formatado é o seguinte:

```
cars = ['audi','bmw','subaru','toyota']

for car in cars:
    if car == 'bmw':
        print(car.upper())
else:
    print(car.title())
```

O problema é que o `else` está no nível de indentação errado. Ele está no seu código [se referindo ao for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops). Você quer que ele esteja no mesmo nível de indentação do `if`:

```
cars = ['audi','bmw','subaru','toyota']

for car in cars:
    if car == 'bmw':
        print(car.upper())
    else:
        print(car.title())

# Audi
# BMW
# Subaru
# Toyota
```